# Form error message not displaying (ASP.NET CORE)

Tags: c#, html, asp.net, validation, .net-core

I've tried and played around a lot, but I can't seem to get my form authentication working.
Before I add functionality to actually create a review, I need to get this working.

The site simply submits the form, regardless of what is in the review text element. It should be catching and displaying an error message if it is blank.

Model:

```
public class CreatedReview
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }

        [StringLength(60, MinimumLength = 3)]
        [Required]
        public string Review1 { get; set; }

        public int? RestaurantId { get; set; }

        public int? UserId { get; set; }

        [Required]
        public int? Stars { get; set; }

        public CreatedReview(string review, int stars)
        {
            this.Review1 = review;
            this.Stars = stars;
        }
    }
```

Index.cshtml

```
@model CreatedReview
@{
}

<h1>Leave a review!</h1>

<form method="post" asp-action="LeaveReview">
    <p>Restaurant</p>
    <input type="text" name="name" />
    <p>Zipcode</p>
    <input type="number" name="zipcode" />
    <p>Review</p>
    <input type="text" name="review" />
    <span asp-validation-for="Review1" class="text-danger"></span>
    <p>Star Rating</p>
    <input type="number" name="stars" />
    <input type="submit" />
</form>
```

Controller:

```
public IActionResult LeaveReview(string name, int zipcode, string review, int stars)
        {
            if (!ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                return View("Index");
                
            }

            // create review blah blah blah (need to accept all of the parameters later)
            var newReview = new CreatedReview(review, stars);
            return View("Index");
        }
```

Comment: try using "asp-for" format.  I think it'll need that for checking attributes tied to the model..  so something like "asp-for=CreatedReview.Review1"  (bind the model... won't need parameters in the method call)